# Fail to configure CommonsMultipartResolver in Spring4

Tags: java, spring

I configure CommonsMultipartResolver in applicationContext.xml like following:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

but it throws exception as following:

```
15-Feb-2017 22:17:35.049 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Feb-2017 22:17:35.107 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
15-Feb-2017 22:17:35.172 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Feb 15 22:17:35 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
15-Feb-2017 22:17:35.240 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
15-Feb-2017 22:17:35.563 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
15-Feb-2017 22:17:35.575 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    ...
```

I don't known why CommonsMultipartResolver failed to be instantiated. I can find CommonsMultipartResolver in spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar.
But this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
```

What's wrong with my configuration?(I'm using Intellij IDEA)

**UPDATE**
this is my applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have tried to solve the problem by adding `commons-fileupload` to IDEA project settings --> libraries. But it does't help, problems still.
[project structure setting of IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiilf.png)

[project structure setting of IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AANU.png)

Comment: Show us your full applicationContext.xml and if possible some part of your java code that references `FileItemFactory`.

Comment: ok, I just add it to UPDATE. My java code never references `FileItemFactory`  `CommonsMultipartResolver` may reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download [commons-fileupload](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4) and keep it in your modules folder of your container. Apparently the class `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` has a hard dependency on `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory` which is a class contained in the above jar. Once your container class loader loads this class, you wouldn't get this error.

Comment: I tried to add it to my IDEA project by adding it to project libraries as I described in **UPDATE**, but it doesn't help. I'm really confused.

Comment: Oh,it's my fault. I just found the problem. I forgot to add the jar `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory` to my artifacts(.war). I add it by configuring `project structrue`-->`project settings`-->`artifacts` -->`output layout`

Comment: I was able to avoid the problem by copying commons-fileupload.jar to the `lib` folder inside Apache Tomcat root folder.

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu. Done. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maven then try

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version> <!-- makesure you put a correct version here -->
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartyResolver` has been superseded by `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver` since all Servlet 5.0+ containers have built-in multipart support now.

Comment: _I'll make sure to document this accordingly._ Document it where?